# kubuntu - what's the best smplayer configuration for best quality in hd movies (mkv)

Tags: ati, kubuntu, video, mplayer

I have ubuntu x64 13.04 with kde 4.11 and smplayer v0.8.6 and the last mplayer version from ppa.

I have ATI video card HD6870 MSI with fglrx driver v13.4.

My kde settings are:

- Composition mode: Opengl 3.1
- graphic system qt: Raster
- scaling mode: precise
- Vsync: auto

So what's the best configuration for quality over performace in smplayer according to my system specs?

For example what do I have to set for the following options?

- enable postprocessing by default and postprocessing quality
- output driver
- Deinterlacing method
- software equalizer
- direct rendering
- double buffering
- draw video using slices
- threads for decoding (MPEG-1/2 and H.264 only
- loop filter
- use CoreAVC

Thanks

Comment: The best way is that you check it for your own. In SMPlayer Preferences(Ctrl+P) go to `Video` tab then `Output Driver:` then chose different options from the list, while playing a high definition video. I think `gl(fast ATI Cards)` would give you best quality and `X11(slow)` would give you high performance. Give it a try..

Comment: thanks, I tried gl (fast ATI cards) but I have got blinking when I set mouse cursor at bottom of the screen when in fullscreen mode during video playing. It does happen with xv (AMD radeon AVIVO video) but I don't know whether xv is the best for quality.

Comment: I was just giving an example. You should try some other options there.. Check in a series, one after another. You'll notice the difference.. ;)